How to query the original and updated description of an item
Let's say I have 2 tables (Postgres if it matters):
CREATE TABLE items 
(
    item_id bigint BIGSERIAL,
    description character varying(2000) NOT NULL,
    date TIMESTAMP default now(),
    -- (many more columns)
    CONSTRAINT "item_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("item_id")
);

CREATE TABLE item_updates 
(
    update_id bigint BIGSERIAL,
    item_id_fk bigint NOT NULL,
    date TIMESTAMP default now(),
    -- (more columns)
    description character varying(2000) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "item_updates_pk" 
        PRIMARY KEY ("update_id"),
    CONSTRAINT "item_updates_item_fk" 
        FOREIGN KEY (item_id_fk) REFERENCES items(item_id) NOT DEFERRABLE,
);

When I insert a new item in table items the description is set. When the description changes, an update is inserted in table item_updates that references the item_id and with that the description is changed and history preserved.
I know how to find the latest description for a given item_id in table item_updates, but where I stuck is the following; a query that gives me the latest description for an item.
For an item_id that has no updates in table item_updates, it should show the description and (many more columns) from table items.
For an item that has updated in table item_updates, it should show the latest description from table item_updates including (more columns) and the corresponding (many more columns) from table items.
The resulting query should contain all item_id entries (+ columns) and corresponding latest item_updates columns.
What I have now is this:
SELECT 
    COALESCE(i.description) AS desccription, *
FROM 
    items i 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         itm.item_id, MAX(upd.item_id) AS uid 
     FROM 
         items itm 
     LEFT JOIN 
         item_updates upd ON itm.item_id = upd.item_id_fk 
     GROUP BY 
         itm.item_id) AS sub ON sub.item_id = i.item_id;

The COALESCE is there because tried COALESCE(sub.description, i.description) but that was not allowed. The result of this query is incorrect however. The error says it can 'see' table sub in the first SELECT statement.
I see many questions and answers when all info is in the same table, but I could not find (or did not have the right search terms) this particular scenario. The answer that CoPilot gave me was also wrong.

Not sure how this sub.item_id=s.item_id is going to work as I see no table/query with s alias.

"The COALESCE is there because tried COALESCE(sub.description, i.description) but that was not allowed." -> If the only change between the posted query and the one you think works (that you should have shared here) is that COALESCE, of course it won't work and the obvious reason was given to you in an error message (that you should have shared too). The previous comment makes it unlikely that this is the query you execute anyway, meaning an untold number of differences between it and the one in your question won't allow us to help.

@AdrianKlaver You're right. I have edited my real query because it is part of a larger system that is not easy to understand. I came up with the description and updates to this description example as an easier to grasp concept. I also just noticed 'AS desc' is probably not allowed as it is also used for ordering DESC. Anyway, where it says s i meant i.
I have edited the question accordingly.

@Atmo I will add the error. I can do that later as I am not able to access that system now.

The query did not get any better: 1) This MAX(upd.item_id) is no going work as item_updates does not have an item_id it has update_id or item_id_fk. 2) Even if it did by using MAX you are only going to get one result from the sub query.

Fixed Setup
CREATE TABLE items (
  item_id     bigserial PRIMARY KEY
, inserted_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
, description varchar(2000) NOT NULL
-- , many more columns
);

CREATE TABLE item_updates (
  update_id   bigserial PRIMARY KEY
, item_id_fk  bigint NOT NULL
, updated_at  timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
, description varchar(2000) NOT NULL
-- , more columns
, CONSTRAINT item_updates_item_fk FOREIGN KEY (item_id_fk) REFERENCES items
);

Fixed a couple of syntax issues.
And I don't use the name "date" for a timestamp column, that would be self-sabotage. Using inserted_at and updated_at instead. And more often than not, you really want timestamptz, not timestamp. See:

Ignoring time zones for Postgres timestamps

Query
All items:
SELECT i.item_id, COALESCE(u.description, i.description) AS description
 --  , i.column1, u.column2  -- whatever
FROM   items i 
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.item_id_fk)
          *  --  or whatever you want
   FROM   item_updates u
   ORDER  BY u.item_id_fk, u.update_at DESC
   ) u ON u.item_id_fk = i.item_id;

Given item_id:
SELECT i.item_id, COALESCE(u.description, i.description) AS description
 --  , i.column1, u.column2  -- whatever
FROM   items i 
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *  --  or whatever you want
   FROM   item_updates u
   WHERE  u.item_id_fk = i.item_id
   ORDER  BY  u.update_at DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) u ON true
WHERE  i.item_id = 123;  -- your input here

fiddle
Related:

How to join a table with a row in another table having the highest id?

About DISTINCT ON:

Select first row in each GROUP BY group?

And how to optimize performance for certain data distributions:

Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user

About LATERAL subqueries:

What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?


I used the version under 'Given item_id' and that works exactly as I needed! Thank you very much.
I will have to study the Related issues that you added because, I must admit, I don't yet fully understand how this works so thank you for those as well!
